# Extended tuple unpacking with unknown string format

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I have a string that *may or may not* have a `|` separator breaking it into two separate parts.

Is there a way to do extended tuple unpacking like this

```
first_part, *second_part = 'might have | second part'.split(' | ')
```

and have `second_part == 'second part'` rather than `['second part']`? If there is no separator, `second_part` should be `''`.

Comment: What if there is no such element. What should `second_part` then be?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `''` see answer below

Comment: Where does the `b == second part` come from? And the `['second part']`?

Comment: @Hatsepsut: ah, I didn't see you answered your own question. Nevertheless perhaps you should add it to the question specs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Done

Answer (score 4):

```
first_part, _, second_part = 'might have | second part'.partition(' | ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
>>> a, b = ('might have | second part'.split(' | ') + [''])[:2]
>>> a, b
('might have', 'second part')
>>> a, b = ('might have'.split(' | ') + [''])[:2]
>>> a, b
('might have', '')
```

The nice thing about this approach is that's it's easily generalized to n-tuple (while `partition` will only split in part before separator, separator, and the part after):

```
>>> a, b, c = ('1,2,3'.split(',') + list("000"))[:3]
>>> a, b, c
('1', '2', '3')
>>> a, b, c = ('1,2'.split(',') + list("000"))[:3]
>>> a, b, c
('1', '2', '0')
>>> a, b, c = ('1'.split(',') + list("000"))[:3]
>>> a, b, c
('1', '0', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = 'might have | second part'

new_val = s.split("|") if "|" in s else [s, '']

a, *b = new_val
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two pitfalls here:

- Dealing with multiple seperators
- Not searching the string twice (i.e. splitting once)

So, if you only want to split on the first seperators (Use `string.rsplit()` for the last seperators):

```
def optional_split(string, sep, amount=2, default=''):
    # Split at most amount - 1 times to get amount parts
    parts = string.split(sep, amount - 1)
    # Extend the list to the required length
    parts.extend([default] * (amount - len(parts)))
    return parts
```

```
first_part, second_part = optional_split('might have | second part', ' | ', 2)
```